# Jquery bold a row in Oracle Apex Classic Report

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

I'd like to bold only rows with values like `Suma:` in Oracle Apex Classic Report. I tried to execute that feature with below code but I do not know how to replace `==` with SQL like clause.

```js
$('#myreport td[headers="PROGRAMY"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == 'Suma:'
}).parent().children().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

The code should bold only rows where `programy like 'Suma:%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other way is to create a column in your query, setting it to Hidden.

```
case when programy like 'Suma:% then 'u-bold' end extra_class
```

Then add the following HTML expression to your existing column

```
<span class="#EXTRA_CLASS#">#PROGRAMY#</span>
```

As for your jQuery, you may consider

```
$(this).text().substr(0,4)
```

eg, check out result of

```
'Suma:abc'.substr(0,4)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a Classic Report, but - why wouldn't you use an **Interactive Report** instead? Its "Actions" already offers **Highlight** which lets you do it with no effort.

For example (left: the "Highlight" options; right: the result):

[image]

Comment: I have to use a Classic Report because of its break formatting attributes